# Jetbrains Rider IDE stopped reading PRs from GitHub Enterprise

Tags: rider

Today when using Jetbrains Rider IDE and selecting the "Pull Requests" tab, instead of the normal list of PRs I got the message: `Could not determine GitHub Enterprise server version`.

I've tried:

- removing and re-adding the connection to our GitHub Enterprise server;
- directly connecting to GitHub Enterprise via the web;
- generate a new token for the connection;
- re-starting my vpn;

...all to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently at least one of the things mentioned in the question *in combination with restarting Rider* did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in v2022.2.2 -> update to v2022.2.3